# Xamarin Starter + Indie VS 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

this is a question about Xamarin subscription model.

I have 1 year of Xamarin indie subscription for free (I'm Student). After I installed VS 2015 with android support I was asked to activate some kind of trial, presumably something to do with starter edition.

Now All apps I deploy have splash screen that says the app is build with evaluation software. I am not sure about size limits. My question is, can I build reasonable sized apps to deploy on app store with Indie subscription and do so using VS 2015 ?

Comment: That simply means your Indie license activation was not successful. Contact Xamarin support and only they can correct that.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin Indie is limited you to code with Xamarin Studio IDE. In order to use VS IDE to develop mobile application, you will require at least Business license (https://store.xamarin.com/)